# stack profiling skipping cost centers in dependencies

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I am trying to profile my program the uses the `hashables` library and others. I don't want to profile the dependencies of my code, I just want to profile my code (and maybe the entry points of the dependencies). I am building with `stack build --profile` or with `stack build --executable-profile` and I am always getting noise like this in my profile (the following is from the `profiterole` output). How can I skip all this and only profile code from my package?

```
...


48.8  10.9   3.5  Data.Hashable.Generic ghashWithSalt (7601904)
45.3   7.5   4.6    Data.Hashable.Generic ghashWithSalt (6569085)
26.9    .3    .3      Data.Hashable.Generic hashSum (3165747)
 6.0   2.3   1.7      Data.Hashable.Generic ghashWithSalt (558817)
 1.6     -     -        Data.Hashable.Generic hashSum (432539)
 1.6    .2    .1        Data.Hashable.Class hashWithSalt (386021)
  .2    .1     -          Data.Hashable.Class hashWithSalt (0)
  .2    .1    .1            Data.Hashable.Class defaultHashWithSalt (186852)
  .1     -     -              Data.Hashable.Class combine (186852)
  .1     -     -          Data.Hashable.Class hashWithSalt1 (0)
  .1     -     -            Data.Hashable.Class liftHashWithSalt (7458)
  .6    .4    .2        Data.Hashable.Class liftHashWithSalt (61434)
  .4    .3    .1          Data.Hashable.Class liftHashWithSalt.step (614548)
  .3    .1    .1            Data.Hashable.Class hashWithSalt (0)
  .2     -     -              Data.Hashable.Class defaultHashWithSalt (614548)
  .1     -     -                Data.Hashable.Class hash (0)
   -     -     -                Data.Hashable.Class combine (614548)
   -     -     -          Data.Hashable.Class liftHashWithSalt.finalise (61434)
   -     -     -            Data.Hashable.Class hashWithSalt (0)
   -     -     -              Data.Hashable.Class defaultHashWithSalt (61434)
   -     -     -                Data.Hashable.Class combine (61434)
  .4     -     -        Data.Hashable.Generic ghashWithSalt (0)
  .4     -     -          Data.Hashable.Generic hashSum (206676)
  .1     -     -        Database.FluiDB.CnfQuery.Types hashWithSalt (70236)
 4.0    .1     -      Data.Hashable.Class hashWithSalt (128078)
  .2    .1    .1        Data.Hashable.Class defaultHashWithSalt (126035)
   -     -     -          Data.Hashable.Class combine (48982)
 3.5     -     -      Data.HashMap.Base hashWithSalt (116920)
  .2     -     -      Database.FluiDB.Cluster.Types.Clusters hashWithSalt (0)


28.7  10.0   2.7  Data.Hashable.Class liftHashWithSalt (539054)
 9.4   1.4    .4    Data.Hashable.Class defaultLiftHashWithSalt (105)
 6.1    .2    .2      Data.Hashable.Class hashWithSalt (90103)
 2.1     -     -        Data.Hashable.Generic ghashWithSalt (264200)
 2.3    .8    .6      Data.Hashable.Class liftHashWithSalt2 (506010)
 1.5    .2    .1        Data.Hashable.Class hashWithSalt (126670)
 1.3    .1     -          Data.Hashable.Generic ghashWithSalt (232657)
  .1    .1    .1            Data.Hashable.Generic hashSum (27468)
  .2     -     -        Data.Hashable.Class combine (195731)
  .6     -     -      Data.HashMap.Base hashWithSalt (846)
 8.8   5.3   2.3    Data.Hashable.Class liftHashWithSalt.step (10374784)
 6.1   3.0    .6      Data.Hashable.Class hashWithSalt (55681)
 5.0   2.4   2.1        Data.Hashable.Class defaultHashWithSalt (9979602)
 1.5     -     -          Data.Hashable.Class combine (8942838)
 1.5    .3    .3          Data.Hashable.Class hash (0)
  .4     -     -        Data.Hashable.Generic ghashWithSalt (164889)
  .4     -     -      Database.FluiDB.Cluster.Types.Clusters hashWithSalt (116428)
 7.2    .1    .1    Data.Hashable.Class hashWithSalt (211986)
 7.1     -     -      Data.Hashable.Generic ghashWithSalt (522861)
  .7    .5    .1    Data.Hashable.Class liftHashWithSalt.finalise (218121)
  .6    .3    .1      Data.Hashable.Class hashWithSalt (0)
  .5    .3    .3        Data.Hashable.Class defaultHashWithSalt (198539)
  .2     -     -          Data.Hashable.Class combine (98093)

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think the best way of doing this currently is to use the per-package `ghc-options` feature of the project-specific `stack.yaml` file to explicitly disable automatic CAF generation for external dependencies.  In your `stack.yaml` file (**not** the `package.yaml` or `.cabal` file), you can add:

```
ghc-options:
  hashable: -fno-prof-auto
```

and then run:

```
stack build --profile
stack exec --profile -- myProgram +RTS -p
```

as usual.

As there doesn't seem to be a way to specify that this flag only applies to the profiled build, this means that `hashable` will need to be re-built especially for your project in both profiled and non-profiled versions, even though the non-profiled version should be equivalent to the "usual" non-profiled version.

Also, even though there are `"$everything"` and `"$locals` flags that can be used, so that the following might be supposed work:

```
ghc-options:
  "$everything": -fno-prof-auto
  "$locals": -fprof-auto
```

the Stack documentation is unclear on how these are resolved and includes multiple vague warnings that the `"$everything"` flag is dangerous.  I couldn't get it to work at any rate.

Comment: I am getting `The following packages specified by flags or options are not found: hashables`

Comment: Oh, looks like the package name is actually `hashable` without the "s".

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I am still getting a lot of noise coming from `hashable` :(

Comment: Well, it worked fine for me using a test based on `primes`, but I don't have a good `hashable` example to test.  You can try running `stack clean` and then rebuilding with `stack build --profile`.  Maybe that will help?